# Как ограничить загрузки файлов по mime type в asp.net core?

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, asp.net-core, облако

Клиент отправляет на сервер 10 файлов, после чего надо узнать какой файл к какому типу относится, а именно image или video, для того чтобы потом сохранить на облаке (для сохранения на облаке фотографии и видео используются разные методы, именно для этого надо узнать к какому типу файл относится). Использую Asp.Net Core Web Api, IFormFile, в качестве облака Cloudinary.

Comment: `IFormFile.ContentType` - хранит MIME тип вашего файла, а вот `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` хранит распространённые MIME типы и соотносящиеся к ним расширения файлов. Так Вы сможете узнать какой файл передали на сервер, изображение или видео.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень помогли.